# Prevent duplicate content penalties when products in e-commerce website are parsed from another website

Tags: seo, ecommerce

I have a website that sells some goods. The problem is that this products are parsed from another website. I parsed name, model, and all technical characteristics. I have more than 2 thousand parsed items.

What is my best option for preventing Google from penalizing my site?
To wrap description in the iframe tag and restrict this iframe from indexing?

Comment: Duplicate content is expected on shopping sites and is treated differently. You will find the site will not be punished for such content but you should also expect not to be rewarded either.

Answer (score -1):

You have some options, but no one protects your content from scraping to 100%. But you can do something against automatic scraping and inform Google about your authorsip. Do following things:

- try to get scraper referers, specially IP addresses and user agents of those who scrape your content and punch them back them with server redirect (if referer == scraper, redirect to `hell`)
- try to inform Google about your primarily authorship of your content: provide shopping feed, publishing date, bind your pages with rel="author" and structured data with your google plus account.
- use your [DMCA dashboard](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/dmca-dashboard) and try to send removal submissions about really every piece of content,
- consult a new media lawyer to make your DMCA submissions more painful in the offline world,
- use in your content some watermarks, like intended errors, transposed digits, doubled commas and the like, so you'll be able quickly google scraped content.

DMCA dashboard should be your first action.

Comment: It sounds like his site is the one scraping product descriptions from elsewhere, but your answer is about protecting his content from *being* scraped.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller haha, seems you are right - i'm on my wave